# convert +44 into 0044 phone number

Tags: sql, impala

How can I change +44 phone number into a 0044 phone number within the select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, `+` only occurs once in the phone number, so you can use `replace()`:

```
replace(phonenumber, '+44', '0044')
```

Answer (score 0):

using concat -

```
select concat('00', replace(phonenumber,'+','')) from tableName
```